# Issues reading CSV file using OLEDB when filename have period

Tags: oledb

Issues reading CSV file using OLEDB when filename have period.

I have a code in C# that reads CSV File using OleDBProvider. It works perfect with filenames in regular format such as Budget.csv but failed when i renamed the file into Budget.DKK.csv or Budget.USD.csv

I throws this exception:
he Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Budget.DKK.csv'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

I have no idea so far why is this happening.

Comment: This might seem obvious, but can you change the period you've introduced into the filename to an underscore, say?

Comment: i cannot do this as this is a product that customers will use. Possibly a trick is to create a copy somewhere, rename, and use it instead. But perfect, maybe i have to sort to another solution.

Answer (score 3):

If [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/22302a07-d599-46c5-be19-6164156e7762/) is to be believed, then it is a known problem that won't be fixed.  It mentions a work-around that allows the name to be forced into the old style 8.3 format.

And just as a random suggestion if you haven't tried it, maybe delimit the filename with brackets `[filename.stuff.txt]`.  I doubt it is that simple, though.

Comment: I wrote sample code based on Mark Wilkins answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22680288/741136