# Reading Excel csv file with extra dot in file name using OLEDB

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I have excel csv file with a dot in file name. (This is the industry naming convention, so I cannot change it.) I am trying to read all data using OLEDB. If I remove the dot from file name, my command works. If not it says invalid object. How to ignore/resolve dot in file name ?

file name : ABC Test bank Trail Feb 2014 $ 18083.65.csv

my code:

```
Public Function GetAllData(ByVal FileName As String) As DataTable

    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using con As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = String.Format(ConnectionNoHeader, Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName))}
            cn.Open()
            Dim SQLAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()               
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(FileName) + "]", con)
            SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            SQLAdapter.Fill(dt)

        End Using
        Return dt
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: if you are just reading the file once, then one trick is to make a copy of the same file with some other name such as abc.csv, then do your query, and delete the file

Comment: Good idea. But the problem is these files are huge and so it might affect performance. If nothing works, I have to go this way.

Comment: +1 other people have had the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22302a07-d599-46c5-be19-6164156e7762/reading-a-csv-file-with-embedded-periods-in-the-file-name-using-oledbcommand?forum=adodotnetdataproviders suggests using the API call GetShortPathName to use the old MS-DOS 8.3 version of the filename.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 'Add this line'

Public Class Form1
  'Add the following line'
  Declare Unicode Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetShortPathNameW" (ByVal longPath As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal ShortPath As System.Text.StringBuilder, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal bufferSize As Integer) As Integer

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dtb As DataTable = GetAllData("C:\Junk\ABC Test bank Trail Feb 2014 $ 18083.65.csv")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
  End Sub

  Public Function GetAllData(ByVal FileName As String) As DataTable
    Try
      Dim dt As New DataTable
      Dim strcnn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) & "';Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""
      Using con As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = strcnn}
        con.Open()
        Dim SQLAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        If InStr(FileName, ".") <> InStrRev(FileName, ".") Then   'Add these lines'
          Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)            'Add these lines'
          Call GetShortPathName(FileName, sb, 256)                'Add these lines'
          FileName = sb.ToString                                  'Add these lines'
        End If                                                    'Add these lines'
        Dim strcmd As String = "SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(FileName) + "]"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strcmd, con)
        SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        SQLAdapter.Fill(dt)
      End Using
      Return dt
    Catch
      Return Nothing
    End Try
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: P.S. I tested this under Windows 8.1 and it works fine